# Alsa or PulseAudio problem

Tags: command-line, sound, 18.04, pulseaudio, alsa

After trying to install an equalizer in Ubuntu 18.04 I have been without audio. The audio only starts when I run the `pulseaudio` command from the  terminal. When I close the terminal, I have no audio output device. I have uninstalled and reinstalled, but nothing happens.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open the terminal and type:

```
setsid pulseaudio
```

PulseAudio won't stop working even if the terminal is closed.

To make this change permanent search for Startup Applications Preferences in the Dash, and add the command `setsid pulseaudio` to the list of *Additional startup programs* by clicking the Add button and filling out the details in the two text input fields after where it says *Name:* and *Command:* . After *Name:* type `PulseAudio` and after *Command:* type `setsid pulseaudio` Then click the *Save* button to save the changes.

Comment: If making the change permanent doesn't work every time you login you may need to put two PulseAudio entries in Startup Applications Preferences, the first entry says `setsid pulseaudio` and the second entry says `pulseaudio`